# Spring + Hibernate loading large amount records

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to find the best/optimal way of loading larger amounts of data form MySQL database in a Spring/Hibernate service.

I pull about 100k records from a 3rd party API (in chunks usually between 300-1000) I then need to pull translations for each record from database since there are 30 languages that means that there will be 30 rows per record so 1000 records from API is 30,000 rows from database.

The records from API come in form of POJO (super small in size) say I get 1000 records I split the list into multiple 100 record lists and then collect id's of each record and select all translations from database for this record. I only need two values from the table which I than add to my POJOs and then I push the POJOs to the next service.

Basically this:

```
interface i18nRepository extends CrudRepository<Translation, Long> {}

List<APIRecord> records = api.findRecords(...);
List<List<APIRecord>> partitioned = Lists.partition(records, 100); // Guava 

for(List<APIRecord> chunk : partitioned) {
  List<Long> ids = new ArrayList();

  for(APIRecord record : chunk) {
    ids.add(record.getId());
  }

  List<Translation> translations = i18Repository.findAllByRecordIdIn(ids);

  for(APIRecord record : chunk) {
    for(Translation translation : translations) {
      if (translation.getRedordId() == record.getId()) {
        record.addTranslation(translation);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As far as spring-boot/hibernate properties go I only have default ones set. I would like to make this as efficient, fast and memory lite as possible. One idea I had was to use the lower layer API instead of Hibernate to bypass object mapping.

Comment: You could paginate your results with `PagingAndSortingRepository` interface instead

Comment: You can cache the data in the database. just give `ehcache` a try , you can add it real quick to test.. only the important thing is how realtime you want your results be.

Comment: Several recommandations are in the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#batch-session-batch. I would add that your nested loops algorithm is O(n^2). Using a Map would turn it into an O(n) algorithm. But anyway: what is your question?

Comment: 1. You should use `join`. 2. You should select a records with `PageRequest` to load data by chunks. 3.If your result is so big. You can use tempolary table for saving results.

Comment: @S.Denis `join`? on what ? PageRequest seem like a good idea.

Comment: @SterlingDuchess Your last 2 `for` is `join`.

Comment: @SterlingDuchess For spring data when you want work with a lot of data you can use `Slice`.

Comment: @SterlingDuchess http://knes1.github.io/blog/2015/2015-10-19-streaming-mysql-results-using-java8-streams-and-spring-data.html

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should bypass JPA/Hibernate for bulk operations.
There's no way to make bulk operations efficient in JPA.
Consider using Spring's JpaTemplate and native SQL.